# Installing the specific angular version not working (Angular 5.2.10)

Tags: angular5

I am trying to downgrade from Angular 6 to 5 but somehow, the way to install specific version is not working on my machine. See below:
*Note: I already uninstalled angular 6.*

[npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@5.2.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACAMG.jpg)

please help.

Thanks in advance!

Here are the logs:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli
>   'C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'install',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '-g',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli@5.2.10' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@6.0.0
>
> 3 info using node@v8.11.3
>
> 4 verbose npm-session 5c326aa0674c8d9b
>
> 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
>
> 6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
>
> 7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 41ms
>   (from cache)
>
> 8 silly registry:manifest no matching version for @angular/cli@5.2.10
>   in the cache. Forcing revalidation
>
> 9 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 1013ms
>   (from cache)
>
> 10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@5.2.10 No
>   matching version found for @angular/cli@5.2.10
>
> 11 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
>
> 12 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1515ms
>
> 13 verbose type version
>
> 14 verbose stack @angular/cli: No matching version found for
>   @angular/cli@5.2.10
>
> 14 verbose stack     at pickManifest
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:65:11)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:52:18)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at tryCatcher
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues
>   (C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
>   (timers.js:745:5)
>
> 15 verbose cwd C:\Users\TEUSER
>
> 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>
> 17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
>   "C:\Users\TEUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "install" "-g" "@angular/cli@5.2.10"
>
> 18 verbose node v8.11.3
>
> 19 verbose npm  v6.0.0
>
> 20 error code ETARGET
>
> 21 error notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@5.2.10
>
> 22 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are
>   requesting
>
> 22 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>
> 23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Then, run (--force flag might be required)

```
npm cache clean
```

or, if you're using npm > 5.

```
npm cache verify
```

[STEP 1] Install an angular-cli specific version

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@wished.version.here
```

[STEP 2] Create a project

```
ng new you-app-name
```

The resulting white app will be created in the desired angular version.

Comment: this is not correct. there remains `No matching version found for @angular/cli@5.2.10`